# VNC just show three options

Tags: vnc

When I log into my account through VNC viewer, I just get the following options:

1.accept clipboard from viewers

2.send clipboard to viewers

3.send primary selection to viewers

[image]

How to have access to the top taskbar, for instance, "application" button? 
[image]